# Gulp watch - execute tasks in order (synchronous)

Tags: javascript, gulp

I have a series of tasks to be run from a watcher but I can get them to fire in order:

Here is the gulp tasks and watcher.

```
gulp.task('app_scss', function(){
    return gulp.src(appScssDir + '/main.scss')
        .pipe(sass({ style: 'compressed' }).on('error', gutil.log))
        .pipe(autoprefix('last 2 version', 'safari 5', 'ie 8', 'ie 9', 'opera 12.1', 'ios 6', 'android 4'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(appBuilderDir));
});

gulp.task('app_vendor_css', function(){
    return gulp.src(appProviderCssDir + '/*.css')
        .pipe(minifyCSS({ keepSpecialComments: 0 }))
        .pipe(concat('app_vendor.css'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(appBuilderDir));

});

gulp.task('app_build_css', function(){
    return gulp.src(appBuilderDir + '/*.css')
        .pipe(concat('style.css'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(targetCssDir));
});


gulp.task('watch', function () {
    gulp.watch(appScssDir + '/**/*.scss', ['app_scss', 'app_build_css']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['app_build_clean', 'app_scss', 'app_vendor_css', 'app_build_css', 'watch']);
```

So when I update a scss file it should compile them create a single css file. Then the build task concats the file with the vendor files. But every time I save a file its always one step behind. See the video as an example: http://screencast.com/t/065gfTrY

I have renamed the tasks, changed the order in the watch callback etc.

Am I making a obvious mistake?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Gulp starts all tasks at the 'same' time, unless you declare dependencies ( or make streams pipe one to the other ).

So for example, if you want task `app_build_css` to wait for tasks `app_scss` and `app_vendor_css` to complete, declare the dependencies,

```
gulp.task('app_scss', function(){
    return gulp.src(appScssDir + '/main.scss')
        .pipe(sass({ style: 'compressed' }).on('error', gutil.log))
        .pipe(autoprefix('last 2 version', 'safari 5', 'ie 8', 'ie 9', 'opera 12.1', 'ios 6', 'android 4'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(appBuilderDir));
});

gulp.task('app_vendor_css', function(){
    return gulp.src(appProviderCssDir + '/*.css')
        .pipe(minifyCSS({ keepSpecialComments: 0 }))
        .pipe(concat('app_vendor.css'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(appBuilderDir));

});

gulp.task('app_build_css', ['app_scss', 'app_vendor_css'], function(){
    return gulp.src(appBuilderDir + '/*.css')
        .pipe(concat('style.css'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(targetCssDir));
});


gulp.task('watch', function () {
    gulp.watch(appScssDir + '/**/*.scss', ['app_build_css']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['app_build_clean', 'app_build_css', 'watch']);
```

Check the [Gulp.task() docs](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#gulptaskname-deps-fn)

Comment: Excellent. Pulling my hair out on that one. TY

Comment: Yeah, me too, until I read the documentation. Using the callback and  promises are also very interesting, in that you can create more complex scenarios, if your project build needs them.

Comment: simple and efficient. also works for example when both tasks are in the default task, without further fiddling. if your scenario is not too complex, I prefer this answer.

Answer (score 21):

With GULP 3 I use [run-sequence](https://www.npmjs.com/package/run-sequence) package to help run tasks in sequence and not in parallel. This is how I configure my `watch` tasks, for example:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    runSequence = require('run-sequence');

gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('templates/**/*.html', function(){ runSequence('templates', 'bundleJS') });
});
```

The above example shows a typical `watch` task which will hook the `gulp.watch` method with files which to be listened when changed, and with a callback function to run when change was detected. The `runSequence` function is then called (within the callback of of a certain `watch`) with a list of tasks to run in a synchronous manner, unlike the default way which runs tasks in parallel.

Comment: Excellent, but better is: `gulp.watch('templates/**/*.html', () => runSequence('templates', 'bundleJS'))`

Comment: gulp-watch is not needed in this example. `var watch` is never used. `gulp.watch` is available on `var gulp`. `gulp-watch` is like `gulp.watch` but boasts several advantages over `gulp.watch`

Comment: This plugin is a temporary fix. The author specifies that in the docs. In gulp 4 the tasks will be executed sequentially as specified e.g gulp.watch([bases.assets + paths.sass], ['sass','styles']); sass tasks will be executed then styles task

Comment: @CengkuruMichael - yes it's quite known for years now. this "temporary" fix has become the standard... Gulp 4 seems will never go public since there are zero updates from the team in their twitter page and no progress on the branch at all on github

Answer (score 3):

## Gulp v4

Now that Gulp v4 has been out for nearly over a year (released at the end of 2017) it offers some great ways to sequence tasks using their library called bach.

https://github.com/gulpjs/bach

**Note**: I would recommend moving to Gulp v4 since v3 had some security vulnerabilities [I'm not sure if those have been patched now].

### Quick Example

Gulp v4 introduces `gulp.series` and `gulp.parallel`, this allows you to create tasks and choose which run in series, parallel, or mixed as shown below.

**Explanation**: This will run the `scss` and `js` tasks in *parallel*, once those are complete it will then run the `watch` task because they're in *series*.

```
const defaultTasks = gulp.series(
  gulp.parallel(scss, js),
  watch
);
defaultTasks.description = 'Builds scss, and js, then watches them for changes and rebuilds upon change.';

module.exports = {
  default: defaultTasks,
  scss,
  js
}
```

### Extended Example

Here's a stripped down example of what my gulp file may look like.

```
const gulpScss = require('gulp-sass');
const gulpBabel = require('gulp-babel');

const paths = {
  scss: [
    'public/stylesheets/*.scss'
  ],
  js: [
    'public/js/*.js'
  ]
};

const scss = () => {
  return gulp.src(paths.scss)
    .pipe(gulpScss)
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
}
scss.description = 'Transpiles scss files to css.';

const js = () => {
  return gulp.src(paths.js)
    .pipe(gulpBabel({
      presets: ['@babel/env']
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
}
js.description = 'Transpiles JS with babel';

const watch = () => {
  gulp.watch(paths.scss, scss);
  gulp.watch(paths.js, js);
}
watch.description = 'Watches for changes to files and runs their associated builds.';

const defaultTasks = gulp.series(
  gulp.parallel(scss, js),
  watch
);
defaultTasks.description = 'Builds scss, and js, then watches them for changes and rebuilds upon change.';

module.exports = {
  default: defaultTasks,
  scss,
  js
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found useful to defines a "series" task with this syntax

```
gulp.task('jsLib', gulp.series(
    function copiaLibJs () {
        return gulp
            .src(paths.lib.files)
            .pipe(rename(function(path) {
                path.dirname = path.dirname.replace(/\/dist/, '').replace(/\\dist/, '');
            }))
            .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.lib.dest));
    },
    function fontAwesomeCss(){
        return gulp.src('node_modules/font-awesome/css/**').pipe(gulp.dest(paths.css.dest));
    },
    function fontAwesomeFonts(){
        return gulp.src('node_modules/font-awesome/fonts/**').pipe(gulp.dest(paths.font.dest));
    }

));
```